# make sure that a macro inside a let form has access to local vars

Tags: clojure, macros

Here is an example:

```
(defmacro aupdate-in [a i f & args]
  `(do
     (aset ~a ~i (~f (aget ~a ~i) ~@args))
     a))
(let [a (long-array [1 2 3 4])]
  (do
    (aupdate-in a 2 * 5)
    (pprint (vec a))))
```

This gives an error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: cina.fn-browser/a, compiling:(/Users/kaiyin/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/cina/src/cina/fn_browser.clj:20:16)
```

I can modify a bit and make it work:

```
(defmacro aupdate-in [a i f & args]
  (list 'do
        (list 'aset a i
              (list* f
                     (list 'aget a i) args))))
(let [a (long-array [1 2 3 4])]
  (do 
    (aupdate-in a 2 * 5)
    (pprint (vec a))))
```

But all the `list list*` stuff looks really ugly. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to unquote `a` so that it refers to the symbol passed in:

```
(defmacro aupdate-in [a i f & args]
  `(do
     (aset ~a ~i (~f (aget ~a ~i) ~@args))
     ~a))
```

Comment: A simple syntax-unquote should suffice - unquote plus a quoted symbol will always expand as the literal symbol `a` regardless of what's passed in, which is probably not what's desired.